# OpenGL glslDevil fails debugging

Tags: opengl

I started using [glslDevil](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/glsldevil/) to debug my OpenGL engine shaders. When I start the program from inside glslDevil all I get in GLTrace windows is the calls to:

```
wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB()
```

which is printed like 1002 times and after that the debugged app freezes and that is it. No debug info or anything else. Maybe glslDevil doesn't support newer OpenGL versions? 
I am using OpenGL 4.2 compatibility mode (but fully programmable pipeline), running Win7 64 bit. The tested software is 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

`wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB` is a function of the Window OpenGL subsystem that retrieves a particular *Pixel Format* configuration. There can be a lot of different configurations available (several hundreds to thousands) and those 1002 calls to it are most likely caused by a loop that enumerates all of them to find a best match.

Other than giving you that information I can't help you much, though.

Comment: Yes I know this, but the devil never reaches the actual render calls. It stuck on GL 1.1 context ...